# XSLT for reading attribute from one xml and replace in another xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files 1. book.xml and 2. Store.xml , I want to read Uid from book.xml and update value in attribute BookId in store.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Book Type="0001" Bkey="book1" BName="abc">
    <Pages >
        <Page LineNo="1.1" >
            <Lines Size="1.00"
                Total="0.00" Lock="N"
               Amount="20.00" Unit="20.00"/>
            <Chars>
                <Char
                    Uid="123456"
                    NoOfChars="1000" Processed="N"
                    Knowledge="Y">
                    
                    </Char>
                                     
                
            </Chars>
            
        </Page>
    </Pages>
  
</Book>`
```

Store.xml

```html
   <bookstore>
   <book BookId="">
        <Bkey> book1 </Bkey>
       <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
       <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
       <year>2005</year>
       <price>30.00</price>
       </book>
 
</bookstore>
```

I need xslt to read Uid value from Book.xml and update **BookId=** attribute in Store.xml

looking for below xml:

```html
<bookstore>
   <book BookId="123456">
        <Bkey> book1 </Bkey>
       <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
       <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
       <year>2005</year>
       <price>30.00</price>
       </book>
 
</bookstore>
```

Comment: *"I need xslt to ..."* - Not how this site works. You post *your own* code, explain what issues you have with it, and people will help fix your code. You don't come here and tell people what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the XSLT which updates the Book Id in the Store.XML. You need to pass the Book.XML as the parameter for the XSLT processing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="book_docu" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="book/@BookId">
    <xsl:variable name="bookKeyFromStore">
      <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/Bkey" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="BookId">
      <xsl:value-of select="$book_docu/Book[@Bkey=$bookKeyFromStore]/Pages/Page/Chars/Char/@Uid" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```